# NoClassDefFoundError while using PDFBox and building with Maven

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox

Greets,

I'm currently trying to read the text of a pdf document.
After trying more then 15 different solutions, the code still
throws this error when I run it with the command "java -jar pdfx.jar":

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
        at com.test.pdf.Main.main(Main.java:17)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Main.java

```
package com.test.pdf;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;


public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args){
     PDDocument pd;
     BufferedWriter wr;
     try {
            File input = new File("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/check.pdf");
            File output = new File("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/Ergebnis.txt");
            pd = PDDocument.load(input);
            System.out.println(pd.getNumberOfPages());
            System.out.println(pd.isEncrypted());
            pd.save("Copy.pdf"); 
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            stripper.setStartPage(1); 
            stripper.setEndPage(1);
            wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
            stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.close();
            }
            wr.close();
     } catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }  

}
```

And the pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>PDFReader</groupId>
  <artifactId>PDFReader</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.test.pdf.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>          
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>  
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId> 
      <version>2.0.11</version> 
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies> 
</project>
```

The jars for PdfBox and common-logging are already added in the classpath.
The Build runs normally without an error.
The pdf file is located on my desktop where i move the jar after the build and run it with cmd.

Comment: See if this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/3124333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this plugin in your pom and execute
java -jar PDFReader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    com.test.pdf.Main
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an actual logging implementation in the POM, maybe like log4j or any of the newer ones.

Comment: Getting the same error after adding log4j api and core in pom and as jar.

Comment: @FightingPlay if that comment was after "greenchecking" the answer, I suggest you open a new question, because there are several log4j versions and several ways to initialize it. (but most likely you'll find answers on SO because log4j problems at the beginning of a first project are quite common)